# integrate step function

Tags: calculus, integration

let $f$ be a step function, $  f:\left[0,2\right]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}
 , f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & 0\leq x<1\\
3 & x=1\\
2 & 1<x\leq2
\end{cases} $

intgerate ${\displaystyle \intop_0^2 f\left(x\right)\,dx}$
  using the $U\left(f,P\right),L\left(f,P\right)$
  definition.

Comment: Choose good partitions so that upper and lower sums are close.

Comment: @GEdgar that's part of the problem, how do you choose good partitions?

Comment: Look at your $f$.  Where can you get upper and lower sums with terms that are *equal*?  How can you minimize difference for the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the graph of the function. Notice that it forms 2 rectangles, one that has width from 0 to 1 and height 0 to 1 and another that has width 1 to 2 and height 0 to 2. The point $f(1)=3$ doesn't it matter since it forms a rectangle with width 0. Choose your partitions so that they align with the steps in the step function.  It should be easy to fill in the details from here.