# A function that depends on properties of the input argument?

Tags: functions, online-resources

I was just wondering if one can write a mathematical function whose parameters depend on the properties of the input argument, and if yes, then how. Say, for example, a function that gives out the square of the argument if the argument if odd and gives out cube of the argument if the argument is even. How do I write this function mathematically? Also, how do I study this function and understand its properties? Any help regarding this, including other resources, would be very helpful.

*PS:* I belong to the field of biochemistry, so I don't have much knowledge regarding mathematics, I just keep studying maths as a hobby; so forgive me if my question is too naïve. Also, sorry for the computer science-like explanation of my question, I ain't familiar with terminology in this field :)

Comment: Look at the definition of a function (for example, in wikipedia). It only requires that the function sends elements of one set to elements of another. It can definitely be defined to give different outputs relating to properties of the input.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679506/how-do-you-show-the-riemann-function-is-riemann-integrable, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134451/integrate-step-function

Comment: In a programming context such a function would be defined using an If...Then...Else construction.

Comment: @daphna thanks for the links, I didn't guess it'd be that simple :P

Comment: @paul yup, that's why I was more curious about the _mathematical_ way to write it

Comment: I guess the point is that to "mathematically define" a function, you don't need a formula. the definition from Hagen von Eitzen's answer is perfectly "mathematical"

Comment: @another'Homosapien' that's part of the beauty (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the definition of such $f$ like this:
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}n^2&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\n^3&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\end{cases} $$